# How to deal with missing attribute values in C4.5 (J48) decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, decision-tree, classification

What's the best way to handle missing feature attribute values with Weka's C4.5 (J48) decision tree? The problem of missing values occurs during both training and classification.

1. If values are missing from training instances, am I correct in assuming that I place a '?' value for the feature?
2. Suppose that I am able to successfully build the decision tree and then create my own tree code in C++ or Java from Weka's tree structure. During classification time, if I am trying to classify a new instance, what value do I put for features that have missing values? How would I descend the tree past a decision node for which I have an unknown value?

Would using Naive Bayes be better for handling missing values? I would just assign a very small non-zero probability for them, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Pedro Domingos' ML course in University of Washington:

Here are three approaches what Pedro suggests for missing value of `A`:

- Assign most common value of `A` among other examples sorted to node `n`
- Assign most common value of `A` among other examples with same target value
- Assign probability `p_i` to each possible value `v_i` of `A`; Assign fraction `p_i` of example to each descendant in tree.

The slides and video is now viewable at [here](https://class.coursera.org/machlearning-001/lecture/preview/181).

Comment: Great info. Thanks. I'll check out the video.

Comment: By "sorted to node n", you just mean among other samples AT node n, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the last point. The value in the current training example can either be "X" or "Y", but the attribute can't hold two values with two pribabilities, right? So what is meant by that?

Comment: It's still either X or Y. Say you have a possibility of 0.9 of X and a possibility of 0.1 of Y (based on all training examples that have this attribute).   Then you use a random function to return a float in [0,1). If the value is less than 0.9, you would assign X otherwise Y. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to leave the missing value as the '?', and not use it for the information gain calculation. No node should have an unknown value during classification because you ignored it during the information gain step. For classifying, I believe you simply consider the missing value unknown and do not delete it during classification on that specific attribute.